# Looking for country timezone database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm looking for free SQL script/database with All CountryName and Country timezone
like :

```
CountryName  | TimeZone(GMT)
-----------------------------------
Algeria      | +1.00
Latvia       | +2.00
```

if anyone have please redirect me for same..
thanks

Comment: you know these aren't fixed right? They change every now and then and then there's daylight savings to account for, which in some countries isn't fixed either!

Comment: Yep I agree,but that doesn't mean..i can't able to find those kind of db :P , should i believe that those kind of database not exist? may be second option, use free web service and write table for timezone?

Comment: Which version of SQLServer are you using? (Support for conversion of timezone data varies between versions of SQLServer.)

Comment: @ mark : Sql Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a page describing timezone handling in SQLServer 2008 [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/03/18/using-time-zone-data-in-sql-server-2008.aspx).

Included within that page is a link to [Sources for Time Zone and Daylight Saving Time Data](http://www.twinsun.com/tz/tz-link.htm).

Answer (score 2):

In **PostgreSQL** you have the system views `pg_timezone_abbrevs` and `pg_timezone_names` with currently 1176 entries including DST information like:

```
           name            | abbrev | utc_offset | is_dst
---------------------------+--------+------------+--------
 SystemV/HST10             | HST    | -10:00:00  | f
 SystemV/MST7MDT           | MDT    | -06:00:00  | t
...
 localtime                 | CET    | 01:00:00   | f
 US/Samoa                  | SST    | -11:00:00  | f
 US/Mountain               | MDT    | -06:00:00  | t
...
```

I would imagine (but do not know) that SQL Server has something similar.

Answer (score 1):

[**Geonames**](http://www.geonames.org) is a well known database for geographical data.

For country time-zones, you can download a txt file with the data [from here](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/timeZones.txt).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use it in C#, I suggest to consider Noda Time (http://nodatime.org/) They are still working on it, but it has many good features.